# Is there a way to tell if a string contains "\u0000" in AppleScript?

Tags: unicode, applescript

I have a string that begins with `E\u0000R\u0000R\u0000`. In other words, each letter of `ERR` is followed by `\u0000`.

`\u0000` is this character: `&#;`

See: https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/basic-latin/0/control-0000/

I'd like to do something like this in AppleScript:

```
if varStr contains "\u0000" then remove "\u0000" from varStr
```

Is it possible, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: Sounds like your “string” is being read from a UTF16LE-encoded text file but using the wrong encoding. The correct solution is to fix your `read` command, e.g. `read aFile as unicode text`.

Comment: Hi @foo, you're probably correct on the encoding. But the string is not get from reading a file; it is from a command that returned an error message. It looks like I can add "as unicode" to the command.

Comment: A “NUL byte before/after each ASCII character” is an easy tell for big-/small-endian UTF16 data. I doubt the AppleScript coercion will help you as it AppleScript strings are always Unicode strings, and the data in that one has already been mis-encoded. You may consider filing a bug report on the app it is that’s producing it. I’ll post a workaround separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, as @red_menace has pointed out, `ASCII character` is deprecated. I was being ignorant.

### This is the correct way:

```AppleScript
if myStr contains character id 0 then
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AppleScript's text item delimiters` to accomplish the task.

Here is an example:

```applescript
set myString to read "/private/tmp/file.txt"

log myString

if myString contains "\\u0000" then
    set curTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"\\u0000"}
    set myString to text items of myString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    set myString to myString as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to curTID
end if

log myString
```

**Notes:**

The test file has literally just the following in it:

```
E\u0000R\u0000R\u0000
```

The `log` *commands* are there just show some output and the `myString` *variable* literally just has `ERR` in it after manipulating it being coerced using `AppleScript's text item delimiters`.

[image]

---

You can also use `AppleScript's text item delimiters` in a *handler* like the one in [Finding and Replacing Text in a String](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH33-SW4)

```applescript
set myString to read "/private/tmp/file.txt"

if myString contains "\\u0000" then
    
    set myString to my findAndReplaceInText(myString, "\\u0000", "")
    
end if



on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry. It appears that your script is looking for literal `\u0000` string? I'm looking for the invisible unicode character `\u0000` (https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/basic-latin/0/control-0000/) and not the literal `\u0000` string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the AppleScript string contains mis-encoded UTF16-LE data (which is the most likely explanation for all the NUL bytes you’re seeing), you can reencode it with some kludging via NSData:

```
use framework "Foundation"

-- extract the string's raw bytes as-is
set d to (current application's NSString's stringWithString:badString)'s dataUsingEncoding:(current application's NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding)

-- reencode the raw bytes as UTF16-LE
set goodString to (current application's NSString's alloc()'s initWithData:d encoding:(current application's NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding)) as text
```

The correct solution is to get the problem fixed at source, which I assume is some elderly/cross-platform application as I’d not expect a Cocoa-based app to screw up a string encoding like that. (Though that will depend on whether its developers still care about an ancient crusty legacy tech which Apple has given up on, so don’t blame them if they don’t.)

Comment: Thanks. I found out in my case detecting if the string contains the `nul` character is enough. Only the error message contains the `nul` character. I don't even need the error message. I can choose either to ignore it or replace the error message with my own error report. But your encoding and decoding may be useful for future use or for other people. I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using a handler (from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/EncodeandDecodeText.html)):

```applescript
on decodeCharacterHexString(theCharacters)
    copy theCharacters to {theIdentifyingCharacter, theMultiplierCharacter, theRemainderCharacter}
    set theHexList to "123456789ABCDEF"
    if theMultiplierCharacter is in "ABCDEF" then
        set theMultiplierAmount to offset of theMultiplierCharacter in theHexList
    else
        set theMultiplierAmount to theMultiplierCharacter as integer
    end if
    if theRemainderCharacter is in "ABCDEF" then
        set theRemainderAmount to offset of theRemainderCharacter in theHexList
    else
        set theRemainderAmount to theRemainderCharacter as integer
    end if
    set theASCIINumber to (theMultiplierAmount * 16) + theRemainderAmount
    return (ASCII character theASCIINumber)
end decodeCharacterHexString
```

I can then call it:

```AppleScript
set u00 to decodeCharacterHexString("%00")
if myStr contains u00 then
    set myStr to replace_chars(myStr, u00, "")
end if


on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace_chars
```

Comment: You can also just set that null character with something like `set nullChar to character id 0` (note that `ASCII character` is deprecated).

Comment: Thank you very much @red_menace. I just learned that ASCII character is deprecated.

Comment: OT, but that `decodeCharacterHexString()` handler is a real Sal Special, so atrociously awful it’s Not Even Wrong. Kill it with Fire. Should you need to decode URL strings in AppleScript, use NSString’s `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`. (Strictly speaking, a URL’s structure and content is solely up to individual servers, but in practice everyone munges URL strings directly using “%XX” escapes to encode characters as *UTF8* byte sequences, so no prizes for spotting what that AppleScript garbage gets wrong.)